# Update values from one object to another in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, properties, key

I have two JSON objects as follows.

```
var j1 = {name: 'Varun', age: 24};
var j2 = {code: 'NodeJS', alter: 'C++'}
```

I need to update JSON j1 with j2.

Desired output

```
 {name: 'Varun', age: 24, code: 'NodeJS', alter: 'C++'};
```

Is there any inbuild function in `NodeJS` to do this, instead of writing our own code.

Thanks and Regards,

Varun

Comment: [Please use the searchbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 5):

Simple `for` loop

```
for (var key in j2) { j1[key] = j2[key]; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/kthVf/

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can implement your own function of inheritance :

```
function inherits(base, extension)
            {
                for (var property in base)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        extension[property] = base[property];
                    }
                    catch(warning)
                    {
                    }
                }
            };
```

then

```
inherits(j2,j1)
console.log(j1)
// Object {name: "Varun", age: 24, code: "NodeJS", alter: "C++"}
```

Comment: I like your answer because you are using a function. What I don't really like is that you are not checking if the property is really owned by the object ... and you should probably return a new object.